# MongoDB on Asp.net: safe synchronous writes

Tags: asp.net, mongodb, synchronization

I'm looking for the best practices on safe and synchronous writes in MongoDB. I have a server on asp.net and mongo database. I have some server methods which can work not only with the same collection, but also with the same object simultaneously. So I need the most efiicient way to synchronize DB writes.

Is it better to do this using mongo API or C# instruments like locks? What about the performance in each case?

It'd be perfect if I make all my `DBHelper` methods (which generally contain more than one atomic operation) run asynchronously when processing different objects (object id is always passed to `DBHelper` as a parameter) and synchronously when working with the same object id.

I'd appreciate any explanations as well as links to related articles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB isn't transactional or ACID compliant so there's no real support for it. If you try using C# locks, you'll run into issues if you have multiple servers as the locks won't be shared across the servers.

If you're just looking for safe writes, MongoDB does offer that, see their documents on [Write Concerns](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/write-operations/#write-concern).

If you are worried about concurrency, they have a [FAQ](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/concurrency/) on that as well. But it sounds like you want optimistic concurrency? This [article](http://late.am/post/2011/11/18/ensuring-write-your-own-reads-consistency-in-mongodb) might be useful.